# Ionic 2 app takes too much time in IOS

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm using IONIC 2.
I've an issue in IOS.
My android app starts within 5 secs, but IOS is takes too much time to load to my home screen...

Please help...

Comment: 1) Do you see such an issue if it is a pure Cordova + mfp plugin application ( no ionic)
2) What is your observation about load times , if the ionic app does not have mfp plugin added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason was SSL handshake failure due to my wifi network. I checked this with Jio network . its takes only 3 secs to load.**

Thank you Vivin and Vittal for your help

Comment: Please describe a bit more how you solved your problem so that it can help others facing similar problem.